# How do i make a YouTube iframe clickable when it is behind an image via z-index?

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, youtube, z-index

I have a page I am making for a client where I need to display their videos from their youtube channel. I have some images of televisions which i have put the YouTube iframes inside of using z-index. As the videos are behind the images I cannot click on them and therefore cannot play them. I have tried using javascript to call a trigger event when i click on the image but with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Attach your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Triggering a click on the Youtube iFrame will most likely not work. I would suggest you to use the Youtube API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

When click event on the image is fired, you'll be able to do a `player.playVideo()`.